# Configure NuGet Client SDK to specify a particular framework

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I have the following code sample (taken from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/cpyfferoen/74092a74b165e85aed5ca1d51973b9d2)) working for downloading a NuGet package and its dependencies to a particular folder:

```
public async Task<HashSet<PackageIdentity>> InstallPackageAndDependenciesAsync(PackageIdentity identity)
{
    bool allowUnlisted = false;
    bool includePrelease = true;

    try
    {
        ResolutionContext resolutionContext = new ResolutionContext(
            DependencyBehavior.Lowest,
            includePrelease,
            allowUnlisted,
            VersionConstraints.ExactMajor | VersionConstraints.ExactMinor);

        INuGetProjectContext projectContext = new BlankProjectContext(Settings.Settings, new NuGetCustomLogger());

        var installActions = await LocalNuGetPackageManager.PreviewInstallPackageAsync(
            LocalNuGetPackageManager.PackagesFolderNuGetProject, identity,
            resolutionContext, projectContext,
            new[] { RemoteNuGetFeed }, Array.Empty<SourceRepository>(),
            CancellationToken.None);

        var sourceCache = new SourceCacheContext();
        await LocalNuGetPackageManager.ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync(LocalNuGetPackageManager.PackagesFolderNuGetProject, installActions, projectContext, sourceCache, CancellationToken.None);

        return new HashSet<PackageIdentity>(installActions.Select(action => action.PackageIdentity));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

This works but it downloads the binaries for all supported versions of .NET (.NET standard 2.1, UWP, net45 etc.)

How can I configure it so it will only download package versions appropriate for a specific target framework e.g. .NET 6.0?

**Edit**
Bonus for information how to load the required assemblies for the target package dynamically at runtime. If I need to modify my NuGet to include json.deps, that's fine.

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://jonathancrozier.com/blog/how-to-dynamically-load-different-versions-of-an-assembly-in-the-same-dot-net-application

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can request the NuGet API with a requested framework.
With the search of a package you have some metadata could help you.
You must need to search and download the package while you find the good metadata.

More info from Microsoft Doc for the NuGet client: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-client-sdk

And this post could help you to find a solution with the desired framework: https://www.daveaglick.com/posts/exploring-the-nuget-v3-libraries-part-2

Comment: but presumably when I install a package into a local project (with the csproj targeting say .net6.0) it uses the same APIs to find and download the correct package + deps?

Comment: From Microsoft Documentation you can search all versions of a package with the following url _https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/[package name]/index.json_.
Example with **NewtonSoft**: https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/index.json.

But you need to know the package id.

More information here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/api/query-for-all-published-packages and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/package-base-address-resource

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).